# Прошу добавить метку [kaldi]

Tags: предложение, метки, добавление-меток

Прошу добавить метку [kaldi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kaldi) для вопроса распознавания речи с помощью инструмента Kaldi
[Распознавание речи. Kaldi. Установка kaldi-asr](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/959070/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8-kaldi-%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-kaldi-asr/959591#959591)

Answer (score 2):

Метки отдельно от вопросов не существуют. В указанный вопрос внёс правку с новой меткой [kaldi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kaldi). Это теперь полноценная метка, и желательно для неё добавить описание.

Comment: Лучше чтоб описание добавлял тот, кто добавляет метку, иначе это будет не скоро. По крайней мере, я лично так постоянно делаю.

Comment: @L.F.C. вероятно, стоит требовать от ТС в подобных просьбах о добавлении метки приводить текст описания будущей метки.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ полностью поддерживаю